# Bug with Unicorn bonus to cut others' reputation

Tags: bug, fun, unicoins, unicorns

I really doubt this is worth addressing anyway, since a) it's (presumably) just for one day, and b) it's just a little goofy thing anyway, but I just noticed the Unicorn bonus to cut other people's reputation by 90% works when you view their profile, but not when you scroll over their name in posts. So...yeah.

EDIT: Guys, it's really not a big deal or anything, I was mostly joking (hence the fun tag) not sure the downvotes are neccessary...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) Nope, it lasts forever.

b) It's not goofy, it's unicorns! We are **serious** here. Sheesh.

(This is status-bydesign. The 90% rep cut is only supposed to make those other users feel a *little* bad, *some* of the time.)

Comment: Man, that would be great if they kept it haha Also I'm very sorry to imply any silliness surrounding the unicorns, I in no way meant to offend :p

Answer (score 6):

Oh my.

I've heard rumours on the grapevine of a bug fix coming for this on April 2nd. Hold tight!